# angular jasmine test abstract class with other abstract class

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, ionic3, abstract-class

I have this scenario problem:

In a Ionic/Angular project(ionic v3/Angular v5) I have the component **SuppliedVanContainerComponent** which extends the abstract class *AbstractLoadingClass* and this class extends another abstract class *AbstractSubscriberClass*.

The *AbstractLoadingClass* use the `LoadingController` an ionic-angular service for showing the spinner and it used by SuppliedVanContainerComponent when call the showLoading methods.

The problem: When I can use unit test with jasmine it show me those error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_getPortal')

And when I go to mock the *LoadingController* with jasmine.createSpyObj, it show me another error and is:

> TypeError: this.loading.present is not a function

**How can I fix it or can I test with abstract classes?**

*SuppliedVanContainerComponent*

```
    export class SuppliedVanContainerComponent extends AbstractLoadingClass
      constructor(loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
            super(loadingCtrl);
        }

      ngOnInit(){
        this.showLoading();
      }
```

*AbstractLoadingClass*

```
import {Loading, LoadingController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {LoadingOptions} from 'ionic-angular/umd/components/loading/loading-options';

import {AbstractSubscriberClass} from './abstract-subscriber.class';

export abstract class AbstractLoadingClass extends AbstractSubscriberClass {
  private loading: Loading;
  
  protected constructor(public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
    super();
  }
  
  private getCreateLoading(opts?: LoadingOptions) {
    return this.loadingCtrl.create(opts);
  }
  
  showLoading() {
    this.loading = this.getCreateLoading({content: ''});
    this.loading.present();
    this.loading.setContent('');
  }

  hideLoading() {
    this.loading.dismiss();
  }
}
```

The jasmine test with error

```
...
  let fakeLoadingController = jasmine.createSpyObj<LoadingController>('LoadingController', {
    create: {content: ''},
  })
...
{provide: LoadingController, useValue: fakeLoadingController},
```

The error:
[image: Error Screen]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @AliF50 the i have two solutions and i post it,
First Solution:

```
....
let fakeLoadingController = jasmine.createSpyObj<LoadingController>('LoadingController', ['create'])
......
providers: [
....
   {provide: LoadingController, useValue: fakeLoadingController},
]
....
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SuppliedVanContainerComponent);
    fakeLoadingController.create.and.returnValue({present: () => null, setContent: () => null, dismiss: () => null});
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

And it's work as simple and without spy or test with LoaderController (just mocking).

If you would work with Loading and spy , to be set in this mode:

```
.....
  let fakeLoadingController = jasmine.createSpyObj<LoadingController>('LoadingController', ['create'])
  let fakeLoadingObject = jasmine.createSpyObj<Loading>('Loading', ['present', 'setContent', 'dismiss']);
.....
providers: [
...
        {provide: LoadingController, useValue: fakeLoadingController},
        {provide: Loading, useValue: fakeLoadingObject},
]
....
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SuppliedVanContainerComponent);
    dailyReportsModel = TestBed.get(DailyReportsModel);
    fakeLoadingController.create.and.returnValue(fakeLoadingObject);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  ....
  it('test fakeLoadingObject', () => {
    expect(fakeLoadingObject.present).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
```

Thanks at @AliF50

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mocking it incorrectly, try this:

```
let fakeLoadingController = jasmine.createSpyObj<LoadingController>('LoadingController', ['create']);
...
{provide: LoadingController, useValue: fakeLoadingController},
...
// before fixture = ..., add this line
fakeLoadingController.create.and.returnValue({ present: () => null, setContent: () => null, dismiss: () => null });
// Or if you want spies on present, setContent, dismiss, you could do
let fakeLoadingObject = jasmine.createSpyObj<any>('FakeLoadingObject', ['present', 'setContent', 'dismiss']);
// then the line above becomes
fakeLoadingController.create.and.returnValue(fakeLoadingObject);
// And then you should have a handle of something like this:
expect(fakeLoadingObject.present).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work fine!! in both solutions working!  I can't upvote your comment :(

Comment: It's okay, no problem. I am happy to help.